# Test for a conservative vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I have a vector $\mathbf{f}$ that satisfies
\begin{align}
\oint_C \mathbf{f} ds = 0,
\end{align}
for any smooth closed contour $C$. I believe this means that
\begin{gather}
\oint_C \mathbf{f} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{e}_x} ds = 0,\\
\oint_C \mathbf{f} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{e}_y} ds = 0.
\end{gather}
where $\mathbf{\hat{e}_x}$ and $\mathbf{\hat{e}_y}$ are unit vectors in the $x$ and $y$ direction. Does this mean that I can also say that
\begin{align}
\oint_C \mathbf{f} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{t}} ds = 0,
\end{align}
and that $\mathbf{f}$ is a conservative vector field? $\mathbf{\hat{t}}$ denotes the unit vector tangent to the curve $C$.

Comment: Can you give an example of a vector field which satisfies $\oint_C f \ ds = 0 $ for any smooth closed contour $C$. I think it is impossible. I assume by $ds$ that you mean $\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}$.

Comment: Usually "conservative vector field" refers to a vector field which satisfies $\oint_C f \cdot \hat{t} \ ds =0$ for any smooth closed contour $C$.

Comment: @Spencer as I know a conservative vector field is defined by $\int_C f\cdot ds=0$ for any chosen closed curve $C$. In particular if $f\cdot ds$ is closed and the domain of $f$ is simply connected then $f$ is conservative. This last is known as Poincaré lemma.

Comment: That is not what you wrote. Your first three integrals lack the dot product with $ds$. You need to define what you mean by $ds$; is it the infinitesimal arc length, or the infinitesimal displacement?

Comment: Infinitesimal arc length is $ds = \sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}$. Infinitesimal displacement is $d\vec{s} = dx \ e_x + dy \ e_y = \hat{t} \sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}$.

Comment: @Spencer In my notation I am using bold to denote vectors so $ds$ is the infinitesimal arc length and $d\mathbf{s} = \mathbf{\hat{t}} ds$ is the infinitesimal displacement

Comment: That is what I gathered originally. There is no nontrivial vector field which satisfies $\oint_C \vec{f} \ ds = 0$ for all closed smooth contours $C$.

Answer (score 1):

My claim is that if $\vec{f}$ is smooth then,

$$\oint_C \vec{f} \ ds = 0 \quad  \text{for all closed smooth contours $C$,} $$ is possible only for $\vec{f}=\vec{0}$.

Consider  a rectangular contour of width $L$ and height $e$. Give the contour rounded edges to ensure it is sufficiently smooth.

[image]

If $\vec{f}$ is smooth, then for sufficiently small $e$ the values of $\vec{f}$ on the top of the rectangle are close to the values of $\vec{f}$ on the bottom of the rectangle. We also have that for sufficiently small $e$ the contributions to the overall integral from the sides is negligible compared to the contribution from the top and bottom.

The result is that,

$$ \oint \vec{f} ds = 2\int_{top} \vec{f} ds + O(e). $$

Now lets suppose $\vec{f}$ satisfies the hypothesized condition. This would mean that,

$$ 2\int_{top} \vec{f} ds = 0 ,$$

for any value of the length $L$ and any orientation of the rectangle. Without loss of generality let the rectangle be parallel to the $x$-axis. Then we must be able to find smooth functions $f_x$ and $f_y$ such that,

$$ 2\int_{x_0}^{x_0+L} f_x(x) dx = 0 \qquad 2\int_{x_0}^{x_0+L} f_y(x) dx = 0$$

If $\vec{f}$ isn't identically equal to $\vec{0}$ then these can't be $0$ for all choices of $x_0$ and $L$. To see this suppose that there is any neighborhood in which $f_x(x)$ is positive. Then we could pick $x_0$ and $L$ so that only this neighborhood is involved in the integration, resulting in a positive value for the integral.

[image]

Therefore there can't be any neighborhood in which $f_x(x)$ is positive. Similarly there can't be any neighborhood in which $f_x(x)$ is negative. All that is left is for $f_x(x)$ to be zero everywhere. A similar argument applies to $f_y$.